# Combine two cell columns into one

Tags: matlab

I have `csv` data like this:

```
Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,OpenInt
2017-09-20,15:35:00,46.98,47.01,46.53,46.89,246802,0
etc...
```

The goal is to return a `TimeSeries` object. I read the file like this

```
function [ TS ] = CSVDataToTimeSeries( FileName )
fid = fopen(FileName);
if fid>0
    data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %f %f %f %f %d %d','Delimiter',',','HeaderLines',10);
```

However this returns me `cells`. **How I would combine column 1 and column 2 into one column (date space time), and leave the rest of the cells as is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate first and second elements with a space in between using [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) and combine with other elements.

```
data = {strcat(data{1},{' '},data{2}), data{3:end}};
```